# infinite scrolling with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, django, infinite-scroll

I followed this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html)

It works fine except for the infinite scrolling part.

Instead of loading more content upon scrolling, it just puts a "more" link at the bottom of the page which loads more content upon being clicked.

Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def home(request):
numbers_list = range(1, 1000)
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(numbers_list, 20)
try:
    numbers = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    numbers = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    numbers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'numbers': numbers})
```

home.html:

```
<div class="infinite-container">
    {% for number in numbers %}
      <div class="infinite-item">{{ number }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
{% endif %}

<div class="loading" style="display: none;">
    Loading...
</div>

<script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
    },
    onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
    }
    });
</script>
```

And this is what i had to add to url.py:

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

Not sure if i need to change something there to suit my needs.

I assume its because of the obvious hyperlink in home.html which is titles "more" but how can i change that so it add content automatically once i reach the bottom of the page instead of when i click the button?